# How to turn "er möge" in indirect speech to direct

Tags: subjunctive, imperative, indirect-speech

The question is on this indirect report in a passage from Book 2 Chapter 5 of Camus’s *The Stranger* (*Der Fremde*) as translated by Georg Goyert und Hans Georg Brenner.

> Der Geistliche betrachtete mich mit einer Art Traurigkeit. Ich lehnte jetzt völlig an der Wand, und das Licht floß mir über die Stirn. Er sagte ein paar Worte, die ich nicht hörte, und fragte mich hastig, ob er mich umarmen dürfe. «Nein», antwortete ich. Er drehte sich um und ging auf die Wand zu, über die er langsam mit der Hand strich: «Lieben Sie diese Welt denn so sehr?» fragte er leise. Ich gab ihm keine Antwort.
>        
>   Er blieb ziemlich lange abgewandt. Seine Gegenwart bedrückte und reizte mich. Ich wollte ihm gerade sagen, **er möge doch gehen und mich in Ruhe lassen,** da wandte er sich mir plötzlich zu und schrie förmlich: «Nein, das glaube ich Ihnen nicht. Ich bin sicher, daß auch Sie sich ein anderes Leben wünschen.»

**QUESTION**

Am I right to think that reconverting to (probable) direct speech would give me the following?

> ... sagen «Gehen Sie doch und lassen Sie mich in Ruhe», . . .

If I am wrong please tell me what is the correct result.  Thanks.

Comment: Wieviele Seiten sinds denn noch? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are pretty much spot on, in my opinion.

The indirect speech construction used here is a very indirect one where there is no 1:1 mapping of the verbs involved. This is because we are dealing with an imperative which cannot adequately be transformed into indirect speech without the help of an auxiliary. *Möge* (i.e. the subjunctive II of *mögen)* is a pretty standard choice for indicating a polite version of the imperative; i.e. we can be very sure that the original uses the formal second person *Sie.*

Comment: Thank you. Then, what does a *du*-imperative become in indirect reporting?

Comment: @Catomic I don’t think there’s a ‘standard’. Possible choices are *soll* or *muss.* The main point being it lacks the implicit politeness of *möge.*

Answer (score 5):

"er möge doch gehen und mich in Ruhe lassen" is an intriguing choice of words for an indirect speech (I suppose it is in french, too) because *möge* indicates a polite expression, but there's no *bitte* and *in Ruhe lassen* isn't a very polite figure of speech.

Since he is talking about what he **intended** to say, it might describe his relationship with the priest, showing his inner irritation as well as his polite external communication style.

I think
*"Würden Sie bitte gehen und mich in Ruhe lassen?!"*
comes closest, but *bitte* isn't included in the text...

Edit: There's one 100% transposition in direct speech, but it's been oldfashioned already when Camus wrote his novel:
*"Gehe er doch und lasse er mich in Ruhe!"*
Doesn't work with "Sie" because the subjonctive wouldn't be recognizable.

Answer (score 1):

> "Möchten Sie gehen und mich in Ruhe lassen?"

Heutzutage spricht man so kaum noch und früher auch nur in noblen Kreisen.

> "Gehen Sie doch und lassen Sie mich in Ruhe."

Ist ebenfalls eine gültige Übersetzung. Sowohl das *doch*, als auch das *mögen*, bekomme ich aber nicht in einen Satz. Das *möchten* betont eher die Höflichkeit, das *doch* eher den Nachdruck der Aufforderung.

Comment: I'll be sure to say *möchten Sie* if ever I get to speak German. Studying it for the present entirely from books and tapes. Thank you.

Comment: @Catomic "Möchten Sie gehen?" is a simple and normal question - "do you want to leave". To turn it into a (still not very clear) request, you'd have to negate the question: "Möchten Sie nicht gehen?" - That isn't common at all but might be used in southern parts. I advise: "Würden Sie bitte....?"

Comment: @Kristina: Möchten Sie dann bitte gehen und Ihre hilfreichen Kommentare anderen unterbreiten ;) ?